# facebook app not working after loging

Tags: php, facebook, api, heroku

i am tray to make an facebook app, i follow the tutorial in this site 
 [FACEBOOK SDK 4.0.0 FOR PHP: A WORKING SAMPLE TO MANAGE SESSIONS](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-manage-sessions/)

first if the user in not logged in then the app will generate a login link,
after logging the app will show the user basic information.

My problem is after logging in, the app show blank page, and the url changed to like this

```
app_url.com/?code=AQCJaz_qzcEzVkJqM-vqfSuX
```

my app hosted in heroku, 
[http://karimfacebookapp.herokuapp.com](http://karimfacebookapp.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For Create App please see :

[image]

[image]

Please put below code in Your index file for app

```
  <html>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*Start Facebook Javascript SDK Call*/
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {  
          // for js api initialization
          FB.init({
          appId  : 'Your APP ID', // APP ID
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
          oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
          });
      };
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";//#xfbml=1";
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=Your APP ID";
        //js.src = "js/connect.facebook.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  /*End Facebook Javascript SDK Call*/

      /** Start script for get login user info */
      $( window ).load(function() {
          FB.login(function() {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  $('.data').html("Name is "+response.first_name);
                });
              });
          });
  /** End script for get login user info */
  </script>              
  <body>
  <?php echo "Chirag Shah FB Demo";?>
   <div id="fb-root"></div><br><br><br><br><br>
   <div class="data"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now run this app, after login it can not redirect on blank page.